# Trying to create an sql subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I'm new to mysql and am trying to write a subquery where I find the player and their phonenumber with the earliest creation date. I'm stuck with getting the subquery to work as the error 'Invalid use of group function' keeps displaying. What am I doing wrong?

SELECT username, phoneNumber
FROM phonenumber
WHERE username = (SELECT username
FROM player
WHERE MIN(creationDateTime));

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT PN.username, PN.phoneNumber, PL.min_creationDateTime FROM phonenumber AS PN
LEFT JOIN (SELECT username, MIN(creationDateTime) AS min_creationDateTime  FROM player GROUP BY username) AS PL
ON PN.username = A.username
```

It should give you the result you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use subquery then get user with min creation date. Then use this user name to get phone number. you can use below query. I am assuming that that will be only one user with min creation date as mentioned by you.

```
SELECT username,  phoneNumber 
FROM phonenumber 
where username =
    (
        select username from player 
        where creationDateTime = 
            (
                SELECT min(creationDateTime) from player
            )
    )
```

There are other better option than subquery.

Answer (score 0):

If you want one player, I would suggest `order by` and `limit`:

```
SELECT pn.username, pn.phoneNumber
FROM phonenumber pn
WHERE pn.username = (SELECT p.username
                     FROM player p
                     ORDER BY creationDateTime
                     LIMIT 1
                    );
```